# Converting float64 to 1 as int, naan to 0 as int

Tags: python, pandas

I am predicting loans, and have a column with number of months since last delinquency. There are many missing values because many people are not delinquent. I cannot fill in zeros, as that would mean they were delinquent. I would like to convert any numeric values to '1', and any Naan to '0'. The column is a float64.

I have tried converting float64 to int(), `train['X25'] = int(train['X25'])` but got TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

What it looks like

```
Loan Number Months Since Delinquency
 1           Naan 
 2            0
 3            3
```

What I want it to look like

```
   Loan      Delinquency
         1            0
         2            1
         3            1
```

Comment: Why do you think that `int(NaN)` would return `0`, or that `int(<some float>)` would return a `1` for arbitrary values?  You described what you want; why not use the functions that check type and `NaN` values, just as you described?  Did you try to look up those functions?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `df['Delinquency '] = df['Months Since Delinquency'].isna()` to get a boolean column

Answer (score 1):

This should work

`df['Delinquency'] = df['Months Since Delinquency'].notnull().astype(int)`